# How can I query including a specific range condition?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to query a database that contains FB users activity.
Example: I try to know the number of followers some important users have. I say "some" because there is a condition which is that I want to see only the users who have between 10k and 50k followers. I would use something like this...(not working btw):

**MATCH (u:Users)-[r:FOLLOWS]->(i:ImportantUsers)
WITH i, COUNT(u) as followers
WHERE u>=10000 u<=50000
RETURN i.Name, followers
ORDER BY followers DESC**

Any idea why this is not working? Every time I execute it appears an error message. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your query just lack an `AND` statement between predicates:

```
MATCH (u:Users)-[r:FOLLOWS]->(i:ImportantUsers) 
WITH i, COUNT(u) as followers WHERE followers>=10000 AND followers<=50000 
RETURN i.Name, followers ORDER BY followers DESC
```

Although a more optimized version of this query is:

```
MATCH (i:ImportantUsers)
WITH i, size((i)<-[:FOLLOWS]-()) as followers 
WHERE followers >= 10000 AND
      followers <= 50000
RETURN i.Name, followers ORDER BY followers DESC
```

Comment: Thank you man! looks cool the oprimized version, it worked!